# Resolving index.html with mapping mentioning path params in URL

Tags: micronaut

I want to serve static resources with path params in the URLs.

I am providing the following configuration in the yml:

micronaut:

```
router:

  static-resources:

    default:

      enabled: true

      mapping: /pr/{id}

      paths:

        - classpath:web/public
```

After building the application along with the React app, lets say I launch the application at - https://host:xxxx/pr/10

I expect my React app to be loaded at the given url with index page and path param having a value 10 (which in my case, I am using inside React Route).

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to happen and there is an error message on the UI - {"message":"Page Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"/pr/10","templated":false}}}

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when building Micronaut backend along with Angular frontend. And I solved it by hash routing in Angular. You can do the same in React (look here https://itnext.io/why-using-hash-based-urls-in-your-react-spa-will-save-you-more-time-than-you-think-a21e2c560879).

The Micronaut router configuration will be:

```
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
        mapping: /pr/**
        paths:
        - classpath:web/public
```

And you can then access the React application on: http://server:port/pr/#/any/parameters/you/want

Comment: `/pr/**` will match anything under `/pr`. If you just want to match for example `/pr/10`, then `/pr/*` is the correct choice